# Он — бизнесмен, она — ?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Может, этот вопрос уже был, но поиском его найти не удалось. А интересует меня вот что. Если он — бизнесмен, то она кто? Бизнесвумен? Бизнеследи? "Бизнесвумен" не звучит, а насчет "бизнеследи"... у нас леди сейчас на всю страну раз, два и обчелся))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле - очень непростой вопрос. 
Он не решается в рамках отдельно взятого русского языка (иначе как волюнтаристическим методом).
Тут завязаны и вопросы использования заимствованных слов, и, как было сказано, идея гендерного равноправия в лингвистике.
Касательно английского. Там вопрос стоит так. Использование мужских форм для женщин невозможно (как, естественно, и наоборот), что очень не нравится феминисткам и прочим эмансипаторам. Приходится, например, заменять "полисвумен" на "служащий полиции" ("police officer"), которое в английском не несет гендерных признаков.

Возвращаясь к русскому. Меня немного коробит от "женщины-бизнесмена", но еще более - от бизнесвумен. Увы, в русском оно воспринимается то ли как ироническое, то ли издевательское... Вопреки всякой здравой логике, но с этим приходится считаться.

Возможно, выходом станет "бизнесменка" по образцу "спорстменка"... А может, как и с полицейскими, импортный вариант не приживется вовсе. Наши-то родные все-таки полицейские, не полисмены.

К сожалению, широко употребляемых слов с подобным "-мен" не так много, выводы и прогнозы делать трудно.

Так что пока пусть будет ***(женщина-)бизнесмен...***

Comment: А  женщина - полицейский,  как ?

Answer (score 2):

Он *бизнесмен*, и она тоже **бизнесмен**. "Леди" и "вуменши" конечно встречаются, но в данном случае я за гендерное равноправие. На ведение дел половые особенности влияют мало, и подчёркивать их в речи считаю излишним.

Answer (score 1):

Деловая  женщина.  Подойдёт ?

Answer (score 0):

...недавно услышал песню на английском про это)))) примерный перевод: я- сексуальный парень, я- прекрасный бизнес. Я- сексуальная девушка, я- прекрасное тело. Слово бизнесмен возникло тогда, когда бизнесом занимались мужчины. Для женщин заниматься бизнесом было не естественно, по этому такого слова не было. Сейчас времена другие, женщину делают из партнера мужчины в его конкурентку. Разделяй и властвуй, одним словом.